# SCSS multiple variables same value

Tags: css, sass

If I have this SCSS/SASS:

```
$a: #fff;
$b: #fff;
$c: #fff;
$d: #fff;
```

Is there any shortcut for this?
In other words, how do I easily assign the same value to multiple variables?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you for some reason need them to hold the same value but need to keep them as separate variables for semantics or readability, or for enabling simple changes down the road you could just do this:

```
$a: #fff;
$b: $a;
$c: $a;
$d: $a;
```

I do this from time to time when dealing with colors that might change during the development process. Here's an example:

```
$background_color: white;
$text_color: #444;
$link_color: $text_color;
$overlay_color: rgba($background_color, 0.7);
```

This is useful since it will allow me to change the value of `$text_color` and have `$link_color` reflect the same changes, while at the same time being able to set `$link_color` to something entirely different. Using only one variable for `$text_color` and `$link_color` alike would mean I'd have to manually look all instances over to see which relates to text and which relates to links. I think a good practice is to name you variables by what they're used for, i.e. `$text_color` and `$link_color` rather than `$blueish_color`.

Comment: Need different variables because am using Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: Even if you need multiple variables to hold the same value, won't assigning one variable and the using that variable to assign the others be the easiest solution? Unless I misunderstand something your goal is to have the same value populate more than one variable right? The only other work around I can think of is using a multiple cursors function, such as Sublime Text's.

Answer (score -5):

Don't use 4 variables, only use 1 if they have the same value

```
$a: #fff;
$a: #fff;
$a: #fff;
$a: #fff;
```

Comment: Probably misses the point depending on the author's need. For example I may want to override !default's of a framework like Foundation but also not litter the rest of my own SASS/SCSS files with their variable names. As an example of why I would do that, well Frameworks seem to haphazardly rename their variables for no reason (like the latest camel-case to dash-case change).

Comment: Also, there's no *point* in repeating the variable declaration 4 times